# javascript indexof issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I have the following code on datatables

```
var colData = table.column(0).data({
    order: 'index'
}).toArray();
var pos;

for (var j = 0; j < csv.length; j++) {
    pos = colData.indexOf(csv[j][PKField]);

    console.log(pos)
    if (pos === -1) {
        // it exists, so we need to add to update list
        // toUpdate.push(csv[j]);
        // toUpdateIds.push(pos);
        console.log("ID found: "+ csv[j][PKField]);
        delete colData.splice(pos);
        continue;
    } else {
        // doesn't exist, so add to create list
        console.log("New ID to import "+ csv[j][PKField]);
        toCreate.push(csv[j]);
    }
...
}
```

I have a csv with 4 rows. 3 entries exists in the database. The 4th is new.
When I import the csv I get the below results

```
POS: -1 ID found: 1371 
POS: -1 ID found: 1450 
POS: -1 ID found: 1485 
POS: -1 ID found: 99999
```

What is wrong with the IF statement and the last row (99999) cannot be inserted on the table?

Comment: uhh `-1` means the thing was not found, not that it was found

Comment: `pos === -1` means that it doesn't exist

Comment: The 3 frist rows exists the forth does not. That is my issue